# Splitting Elements of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = ["1,JOAQUIN", "2,BERNARDINO", "3,MODOC", "4,MADERA"];
```

I would like to split it individually like

```
1 JOAQUIN
2 BERNARDINO
3 MODOC 
4 MADERA
```

What I'm trying is to:

**1. show the numbers(first index) in jQuery UI Autocomplete list**
*2. and their respective name in another textbox.*

Here is my code,

```
var arr = ["1,JOAQUIN", "2,BERNARDINO", "3,MODOC", "4,MADERA"];
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: json,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        var str = ui.item.value.split(',');
        var lastIndex = str.length -1;
        $('#two').val(str[lastIndex]);     //ACHEIVED 2nd   
    }
});
```

However I have got my second point and struggling to find a solution for my 1st question.

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/1/)

Please share your suggestions and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) documentation you can set an array of objects as the `source` property.

> The `label` property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The `value` will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only `value` properties, the `value` will also be used as the `label`.

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: arr.map(function(elem) {
              return { 
                 'label': elem.split(',')[0], 
                 'value': elem.split(',')[1] 
              }
    }),
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#two').val(ui.item.value);    
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETwtF/

Please note that older versions of IE do not support the Array's object `.map()` method, you can either use a ES5 shim or use jQuery `$.map()` utility function instead:

```
$.map(arr, function(_, elem) {
     return { 
         'label': elem.split(',')[0], 
         'value': elem.split(',')[1] 
     }
});
```

Comment: +1 amazing.  I like that return statement within source.  If you noticed that both the textbox is filled with same value.  With help of @Pragnesh Chauhan answer I achieved http://jsfiddle.net/ETwtF/1/

Answer (score 1):

just add `return false;` to your code

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Gm9Bz/4/)**

```
<input type='text' id="one" />
<input type='text' id="two" />  

var json = ["1,JOAQUIN", "2,BERNARDINO", "3,MODOC", "4,MADERA"];
$('input').autocomplete({
  source: json,
  select: function(event, ui) { 
      var str = ui.item.value.split(',');
      var lastIndex = str.length -1;
      $('#one').val(str[0]);
      $('#two').val(str[lastIndex]);     //ACHEIVED 2nd   
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 `return false`.  However the dropdown list of autocomplete is still showing both the values.  Anyway thanks, here is the complete fiddle I needed http://jsfiddle.net/ETwtF/1/